# Java version for Cassandra

Tags: java, cassandra

I have two versions of Java (Java 7 and Java 8) on my machine. 
`JAVA_HOME` set to Java 7. But I want to start my Cassandra with Java 8.

Is it possible to do that without changing of the `JAVA_HOME` value?

Comment: You can always setup a different JAVA_HOME for any script/tool/... that you are starting. The point is: it is your choice if anything that you call is using some system default, or a value that is only used for this very tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the environment variable JAVA_HOME and set it to java8 path

This change will only be impacting  current running shell.

```
 export JAVA_HOME = path_of_your_java_8
```

Start Cassandra in this shell

All other shell will use old java 7